# Add a series of checkboxes to theme options

Tags: themes, options

Hi I made a theme options by [this tutorial](http://www.vitali-software.com/web-design/wordpress-tutorial-add-an-options-page-to-your-wp-theme/)

This options have multicheck type by checkboxes. I don't know how to make it work. I'm try to exclude page using this multicheck.
This is my array with options:

```
$pages = get_pages('sort_column=post_parent,menu_order');
$pageids = array();
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $pageids[$page->ID]= $page->post_title;
    }
array( "name" => "Exclude page",
        "desc" => "",
        "id" => $shortname."_excludepage",
        "type" => "multicheck",
        "options" => $pageids,
        "std" => ""),
```

This screen show how this function looks in my DB:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFwV7.png
```

`512` is the ID of a page that I try to exclude.

Look's like this in admin:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/31TQa.png
```

In my template I've use this standart method for exclusion:

```
wp_list_pages("exclude=get_option('src_excludepage'));
```

Please help me with this function! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Want some honest advice? Work from a better code base..

Though, it's not your fault, there are hundreds of blogs with variations of similar code, i'm not sure where it originated, but i see similar code "alot"...

If you can get by without the hand holding and just manage with a good code base, i'd suggest the following..

http://themeshaper.com/sample-theme-options/

It's not the most fancy or advanced example, but the approach is sound, it only uses a single option to store all the values and also uses the settings api for handling options.

Comment: +1, altough the themeshaper code could also be improved, but it's much better than OP's tutorial source

Comment: Yes, totally agree, but there's really not many good examples to be found, that's the best i've found that keeps the information short and sweet(to the point). I'd love to see a better example for themes, i couldn't find one (search terms are too general for this kind of information) from some brief searching.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Yes it's much better when uses a single option but to many work need to made for implement this options.
http://clark-technet.com/2010/01/wordpress-theme-options-framework-ver-2 -Maybe this much better?

Comment: Unfortunately that approach also uses several options(ie. not singular).. again looks like it's based of the same code as the previous site you linked to.

Comment: ok, first thing, using a array with fields like "textarea", "checkbox" etc.., then using foreach(type...) is ridiculous :) The theme options need to be flexible. You may want to add text, images above, or below a certain option... Try my example from the linked question and after you implement that for your site I can help you add a option that uses multiple checkboxes. And you'll see how easy and little code it uses...

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Assuming your back-end works, and you can check multiple fields, and that the field values are really stored as an array, use:</strike>

```
$exclude = get_option('src_excludepage');
wp_list_pages(array(
      "exclude" => implode(',', $exclude['options']),
   ));
```

PS: the tutorial you use has a pretty weird way of handling "multicheck". A much easier method is to append `[]` to the checkbox input names...

**Update:**

in the `mytheme_admin()` function add another case:

```
 case "page_multicheck":
  option_wrapper_header($value);

  $pages = get_pages('sort_column=post_parent,menu_order');
  $pageids = array();
  foreach ($pages as $page){
    $pageids[$page->ID] = $page->post_title;

    $input_id = $value['id'] . '_' . $page->ID;
    $checkbox_setting = get_settings($value['id']);
    if (in_array($page->ID, $checkbox_setting)) $checked = "checked=\"checked\""; else $checked = "";
     ?>
     <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>[]" id="<?php echo $input_id; ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
     <label for="<?php echo $input_id; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></label
     ><br />
     <?php
  }
  option_wrapper_footer($value);
  break;
```

in the `$options` array remove the old option and add:

```
  array("name" => "Exclude page",
        "desc" => "",
        "id" => $shortname."_excludepage",
        "type" => "page_multicheck",
        "options" => array(),
        "std" => ""),
```

now, theoretically my code above should work...

Comment: @AmbitiousAmoeba: If you have a good tutorial give me a link. Your solutions doesn't work. I have an error on pages:
`Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in Z:\home\mysite.net\www\wp-content\themes\dddd\content.php on line 21`

Comment: add a line with `print_r($exclude);` before wp_list_pages and post here what you see

Comment: @AmbitiousAmoeba: Nothing is happen. All still on the same place.

Comment: well the problem is that you don't know the option name :) try replacing in my code `'src_excludepage'` with `'src_excludepage_512'` (the one from you db screenshot). also do a `print_r` so we can see if it's really a array...

Comment: @AmbitiousAmoeba: Now they show `true`, like in db for options name. I think instead `true` must be pageID and options name must be without numbers only `src_excludepage`.

Comment: so now we know that the option name has the option value in it's title. that sounds ridiculous :) let's clear this out. You have a theme options page that contains a list of checkboxes. What are these checkboxes for? To exclude pages from a menu? Does each checkbox represent a page? Or better yet, make a screenshot of this page, or just post the entire code...

Comment: here's a related question, how to create theme options: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4712/creating-a-theme-option-page/5439#5439 - it doesn't explain how to treat a multiple checkbox option, but it's a good start

Comment: @AmbitiousAmoeba: I've edit the first post. I have a worked theme options and now I only want to add multicheck.

Comment: so the checkbox list is not really dynamic, and you have only 2 options, Home & Portfolio?

Comment: no, my screen only for demonstrate. The main purpose of my screen is to demonstrate how this option look. I have more than 2 options. Every page has it's own checkbox.

Comment: ok, update my answer, see if that works...

Comment: I don't understand what we have in `array()`? With your code I have a blank place in theme options. We must have array of pages.

Comment: that array should contain only the list of excluded pages, not all the page IDs. try it...

Comment: I try it and get blank place where options must be.

Comment: I give up... You should follow t31os's advice and find a better theme settings tutorial

Comment: Never don't give up :) Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AmbitiousAmoeba: I got your code displayed in the options, but the checked pages are not saved. I have a warning on the second value in_array, tried to make this `$checkbox_setting = explode(',',get_settings($value['id']));` and warning was disappeared. After this option_value in db looks not good :
`a:2:{i:0;s:2:"on";i:1;s:2:"on";}`. I think explode isn't right way.
What should i need to do for saving?

Comment: @AmbitiousAmoeba - can you help me? Can you explain what this mean?

Comment: @Denis Belousov: that's a serialized string meaning that the value is a array. Explode expects a string. If I have the time I'll write a tutorial on how to implement theme settings, including a multicheckbox option.

Comment: @AmbitiousAmoeba - I change my `add_admin()` and with your code all works with only one error `Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in ...` for this line
`if (in_array($page->ID, $checkbox_setting)) $checked = "checked=\"checked\""; else $checked = "";`.  They show up until the moment I don't checking at least one checkbox. What should I need to do? Thank you.