# how do you create an admin interface in plugin for your theme

Tags: theme-development, wp-admin, functions

I'm creating a theme that would need some settings on the client side. So I need a admin interface where they can set some values. (like, source of image, title, or numbers)

so in my theme, I can just set some variables like `<img src="IMAGE_SOURCE" title="TITLE" size="NUMBER" />`

If you can point me to a tutorial that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a theme option page?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4712/creating-a-theme-option-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newest and most complete tutorial to the settings API can be found [here](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/?all=1). I'd suggest to take a look there. I used a pretty similar way myself.

Sidenote: You should really mark some answer a solution. "0% acceptance rate" will people hold back from answering your Qs anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to point out single tutorial, a lot of info around dates back to oldish versions and now it's better done with [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API). So check that for foundation and there are some links at the end for more written out examples.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to get a theme that has a settings menu and use it as an example. The one I use (LightWord) has one, so it could be a starting point... You can find it at http://students.info.uaic.ro/~andrei.luca/blog/lightword-theme.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're doing is just basic theme settings that don't require a lot of programming customization, and you want to get it up and running fast, I would recommend just including [cheezcap](http://code.google.com/p/cheezcap/) or another theme options framework...