# framework for plugin/theme options panel?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, options

I found that the longest part of a plugin or theme development is creating the options panel, at least in my case.
So i like to know what's your take on that.
Do you use a ready made framework or class? And if so witch one?
Or do you write it up from scratch?  Use the settings API or plain options?

Thanks.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4712/creating-a-theme-option-page/5439#5439

Comment: @One Trick Pony I don't think this is duplicate, asking about components to speed up development is considerably different from asking how to do it in vanilla WP

Comment: @Rarst , that's right , and also your take on in, (your being the community)

Comment: @בניית אתרים by the way if you end up using something in practice please write about that solution in [WordPress frameworks and parent themes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/wordpress-frameworks-and-parent-themes) community wiki question.

Comment: @Rarst I will!!

Comment: BTW looks like a good adept for a Community Wiki to me. What do u think?

Comment: i agree i already bookmarked this question page.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OK so found some more:

- JeffreyWay /
  WordPress-Theme-Options-Page  -
  open source class the project is hosted on github aimed at theme developers, 
  looks nice, haven't used it. (link dead)
  .
- devinsays / Options-Framework -
  open source Framework the project is
  hosted on github aimed at theme
  developers , i later learned that is
  has evolved in to 
  Thematic-options very large
  scaled project that has lots of
  features. (link dead)
- helgatheviking /
  thematic-options-KIA -    open
  source Framework the project is
  hosted on github aimed at help
  developers build options into their
  thematic child themes , witch was
  forked for Thematic-options very much
  up to date.(link dead)
- [Wordpress AdminPage Class](http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-adminpage-class/115872) - a
  commercial solution, packed it
  features and very easy to use.
- [OptionTree plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/option-tree/screenshots/) - and IDE for
  creating option panels , lots of
  feature and constantly updated,
  downside is: it's not easily
  integrated in plugins or themes and
  default options are not an option (up
  to version 1.1.1).

that's it for now but still looking to here about your experience.

### Update

After a long time of trying I've managed to integrate Options tree with my plugin and after that part was done , I have to say that its never been easier to add options to my plugin, EVER! all done with no code, but using the slick UI that comes with it.
So as of now its my favorite with a small exception of being a plugin by it self and not a framework witch makes the integration part a lot harder.

### Update2

If you read the first update then this will be 180 degree turn, i have stopped using Option-Tree witch was hard to integrate in the first place but mainly for the reason that it create an option row in the options database table for each option you add to it so my plugin has created 287 rows in the database and thats bad for many reasons but the main ones are its hard to remove all of them at plugin deactivation and you have to create a get-option call for each one of them so that's a lot of database calls.
Since that little set back,I found that most of the frameworks listed up here work in the same manner of each option gets its own row.
So i modified AdminPage Class to save all options per admin page in an array of options and and now my plugin only generates 7 Rows in the database and at most i only need to call the get_option function 7 times so that saves lots of database calls, I'll contact the creator of AdminPage Class and ask him to consider this modification but other then that it very easy to use and even easier to manage.

### Last Update

if anyone is still keeping score here, then i ended up coding my own

### [**`option panel class`**](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/my-options-panel)

[image]
which  it's main features are:

- Open source, GPL licensed.
- Works with plugins as well as themes
- OOP Code all the way (which means easy to extend and modify).
- Import Export Options.
- All Options saved as a single row in a database.
- Available fields are:

  - Input
  - Textarea
  - Radio button
  - Checkbox
  - Select Dropdown
  - File Upload
  - Image Upload
  - WYSIWYG editor
  - Date Picker
  - Time Picker
  - Color Picker
  - Taxonomy List Dropdwon or checkboxes
  - Post list Dropdown or checkboxes
  - WordPress User Roles Dropdown or checkboxes
  - Syntax Highlighted Code Editor (PHP, CSS, HTML, JAVASCRIPT)
  - Typography Field (set of size, color, face, family fields)
  - Sortable Drag & Drop
  - Repeater Field
  - Plupload field
  - hooks and filters all over the place so you can customize just the way you'd like

Comment: Great work! Any plans to add tabular data?

Comment: @Kevin, tabular like what?

Comment: I'm looking for an options framework that supports a table of entries that I can add data to and potentially sort/re-order. I'd like to configure the columns and allow them to be filled in. I'm not sure if this is in the scope of an options framework or if it should be handled by a custom post type.

Comment: Simply **jaw droping**... Mi∫∫ing wørds here... Basically this A deserves [this score](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1287812), no less. . . . Cannot wait to play with this :o[) . . . . Wouldn't the **`Last Update`** be better placed on top? . . . And **`option panel class`** in <h1>? . . . Again: WOW, gazzillions thanks for this!

Comment: thanks for the kind words, let me know what you think after you use it.

Comment: is this what i have been looking for my whole life!?  :)  i'm honored my humble options panel got included in the answer.  i actually think devin's OF framework evolved out of his thematic options and not the other way around.  i tried to one-up him, but then he blew me out of the water w/ OF. i wish i could use OF for plugins and have toyed w/ porting it. can't wait to check out your class.  thanks!!

Comment: @Bainternet the first three links are broken. Please update.

Comment: Options-Framework only saves one serialized array for all your options. quite decent.

Answer (score 8):

- [scbFramework](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/scb-framework/) has related classes, I used it for one plugin and it saved me plenty of time;
- [WPAlchemy MetaBox](http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) I see a lot of mentions for this around, hadn't used it myself yet;
- [Hybrid Core](http://themehybrid.com/hybrid-core) has set of functions for pages/metaboxes/settings, but it probably won't make sense to use it just for that.

Comment: That is interesting for some reason I never though just using a page template with meta boxes for a theme options page and WpAlchemy looks interesting.

Answer (score 8):

The UpThemes team has just released their [options framework](https://github.com/LiftUX/UpThemes-Framework) as an opensource for everyone. It worth to take a look.

Answer (score 5):

I had been using this , I liked how it outputs a iframe preview, but I started to just write my own since I'm figuring this stuff out.

http://clark-technet.com/2010/01/wordpress-theme-options-framework-ver-2

Answer (score 1):

The devinsays Options-Framework has now evolved more, into the [Options Framework Plugin](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-plugin/)/[Options Framework Theme](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/).

This is beautiful and user-friendly, and there is documentation about including it right in your theme code. However, if you wanted to incorporate it into a plugin, that would take some work.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can add Infinity Theme Anti-Framework to this list. http://infinity.presscrew.com/

Comment: I've heard of it but never seen or used it, share you exp.

Comment: First of all, they have best image upload system. I am 100% certain on that. I am exploring other sections.

Comment: Update: I think i found my theme system for wordpress. I dont think there is any other theme framework like infinity.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Its soon going out of beta. I think it will be more better to wait for it.