# Wordpress theme options and insert default value for serialize data

Tags: themes, php

How to add default values for theme options? Currently I use basic option from [this site](http://themeshaper.com/sample-theme-options/)

The sample will stored option value in serialize on database. When we activate the theme, there is no value in database at first time until we click Save Changes button.

Now I want add default value when theme activate something like this.

```
option_id   blog_id     option_name     option_value                                              autoload 
152           0           theme_data      a:16:{s:12:"html_doctype";s:1:"1";s:14:"header_fav...     yes
```

Or how do I tweak current sample option to save not in serialize to database

```
option_id   blog_id     option_name     option_value    autoload 
152           0           html_doctype    1               yes
```

Let me know.

Comment: How are your options generated, are they stored in one big array? Settings defaults is a matter of checking if data exists in the option, and setting it when it doesn't..

Comment: @t31os yes stored in one big array. register_setting()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over your array of options and generate a set of defaults from that..

Let's imagine your array looks something like this.. (but obviously bigger)..

```
$your_options = array(  
    array( 
        'name' => 'option-one',
        'desc' => 'Option one description',
        'type' => 'text',
        'std'  => 'default_value'
    ),
    ..and so on.. for each option..
);
```

First check if you have options, if not, it's the first install so you can set defaults.

```
$my_var_that_holds_options = get_option( 'your_theme_options_name' );
if( !$my_var_that_holds_options ) {
    // Do code to setup defaults
}
```

The code to setup defaults will of course go where i've put `// Do code to setup defaults`.

First, create an array to hold the defaults and loop over the options array to build the new defaults array.

```
$defaults = array();
foreach( $your_options_var as $option_data ) {
    $defaults[$option_data['name']] = $option_data['std'];
}
```

By the end you'll have an array of option names and default values, which you can then send to the database.

```
update_option( 'your_theme_options_name', $defaults );
```

If you code needs to loop over the options to set boxes checked, etc.. simply call get_option again after you've saved the defaults..

```
$my_var_that_holds_options = get_option( 'your_theme_options_name' );
```

Or use the defaults array.

```
$my_var_that_holds_options = $defaults;
```

I've had to be quite general with the example, because the approach will differ depending on how your options array is structured.

The important factor here is to ensure your array of options holds a "default" value(std in the example) for each option else you've got nothing to form your default values from.

I've converted themes to do this a handful of times, if you have trouble implementing this feel free to pastebin your file with the options array and i'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I really appreciate it. Make me clear in some part. Let me try to implement this approach. Need a time for me to understand everything :) just beginning. BTW this is http://pastebin.com/K4Hz6rDA a sample theme option I'm working on it. I want stored 5 defaults value after theme activate.

Comment: It might be easier for you to build off a more complete code base(theme shaper code is only a sample/example) that has the bulk of the work done, the **devinsays / Options-Framework** linked to in: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7472/framework-for-plugin-theme-options-panel/7501#7501 might be a good starting point for you.

Comment: yes I was tried devinsays option pages. make me dizzy to know from zero to hero :)

Comment: looks like I need to follow another approach like your answer. thanks t31os