# Is there any plugin development framework

Tags: plugin-development, framework

Since I am new to WordPress plugin development I have been examining the internal structure of many plugins. I have found that most of them don't fit any pattern and so understanding how they work can be difficult.

I was wondering if there is more generalized way of plugin development, possibly with a framework, other than the methods described in official documentation.

Comment: Have you [read my article about OCP](http://unserkaiser.com/code/wp/wordpress-code-evolution-ocp-for-the-rescue/)? I'm already at the point where I say that there's no framework that will always work out.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no official/standard framework, and there will be as many plugin development styles as there are shades of white in north pole.

I'd say [WordPress Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards) is a blueprint for a good style.

You'll find **lots** of good examples and excellent coders here in WPSE. A nice starting point: [questions/tagged/plugin-development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=votes&pagesize=50).

Highlighting:

- [Objective Best Practices for Plugin Development?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/715/12615)
- [framework for plugin/theme options panel?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/7472/12615)
- [What Plugins Demonstrate Great WP Plugin Development?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/17903/12615)

Nowadays, I use [Plugin Class Demo](https://gist.github.com/toscho/3804204) from [@toscho](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho) as base for many plugins.

Right now, [@Pippin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2418/pippin) is doing a series [Introduction to WordPress Plugin Development 101](http://pippinsplugins.com/introduction-to-wordpress-plugin-development-101/) that may be of interest.

*[ **update**, thanks to [@Wyck](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1509/wyck) contribution, a list of helper-plugins/boilerplates/frameworks ]*

Plugin [***scbFramework***](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/scb-framework/), by [@scribu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/205/scribu):

> A set of useful classes for faster plugin development.
>   This is a plugin toolkit that helps developers write plugins faster. It consists of several classes which handle common tasks, such as generating settings pages, creating database tables and more.

[***WordPress-Gear > PHP Boilerplate > Plugin stuff***](http://wpgear.org/)

1. [Plugin boilerplate](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) by @tommcfarlin
2. [Object Oriented Plugin Template](https://github.com/convissor/oop-plugin-template-solution)
3. [Settings framework](https://github.com/gilbitron/WordPress-Settings-Framework) by @gilbitron
4. scbFramework - Classes for plugin dev
5. [WordPress Settings API](https://github.com/tareq1988/wordpress-settings-api-class) - by @tareq_cse
6. [WP MVC](https://github.com/tombenner/wp-mvc) - MVC framework to create plugins

Comment: I would also mention http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/scb-framework/ and there are some listed here under PHP Boilerplate: http://wpgear.org/

Answer (score 6):

Two more newer frameworks are:

- http://getherbert.com/
- http://framework.themosis.com/

Both share similarities with Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

You can also generate your personalized version of Tom's [Plugin boilerplate](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) [here](http://codegen.kickapz.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe Sunrise (http://gndev.info/sunrise/) is the kind of thing you're asking for. It's relatively new, and I haven't used it myself, so I offer no recommendations. However, it looks quite promising. It's available on WordPress plugin directory as a plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/sunrise/.

Comment: Sorry, but this is about _deployment_ and _not development_.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this one is very simple and basic base structure.  https://github.com/softmixt/simple-wordpress-plugin-framework