# Theme Options Panels, What are some good examples from Frameworks or Premium Themes?

Tags: theme-options, framework, user-interface

I really like https://github.com/devinsays/options-framework-plugin

Does anyone know any other good implementations of an options panel from a Framework or from another premium Theme? I think its a major factor in deciding whether to use a theme. I'd like to get a good list of whats being done out there. Wordpress StackExchange Community, what are your thoughts in general this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of the few I've seen, I think that most "premium" Themes *way* over-complicate Theme Settings pages. I generally prefer Theme Settings pages that maintain the style/layout of the rest of the WP-Admin UI. So, these would be my rules of thumb:

1. Incorporate meaningful settings, and not necessarily every possible setting under the sun.
2. Organize settings logically.
3. Maintain consistent layout/style with the rest of the WP-Admin UI, including Settings fields, sections, and page tabs. *Note: use of the Settings API makes this dead-simple.*

Comment: 3) [RESPONSE] - Keeping A UI that is consistent with the WP UI is really important in my opinion as well...some frame works like THESIS stray too far in my opinion.  It confuses my clients on occasion.  Thanks for the input...I'll have to think about "Organize settings logically" a little more...

Answer (score 4):

Takea look at [**framework for plugin/theme options panel?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7472/framework-for-plugin-theme-options-panel) and [**WordPress frameworks and parent themes**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/wordpress-frameworks-and-parent-themes)

which both together list a very large number of frameworks and themes to use with there pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not like theme option panels. The reason why is to much bulk. I don't mind if there are a few options like easy logo changing, fixed or fluid width, and some other low options. I tend to just stick with hard coding any thing into a theme without options unless a client wants that.

And as far a frameworks are you talking about what yootheme's warp, rocket themes gravity, etc. Is that what you mean by frameworks. If so i don't care for these as much as some plugins do not work well with them

Comment: I think from a developer stand point you tend to meet a variety of clients. Not all of them need or want control over everything. While some are inclined and would prefer more control.  I was looking for good models out there to compare between some of my clients demand for features. In terms of Framework, i was thinking along what @Bainternet was mentioned http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/wordpress-frameworks-and-parent-themes

Comment: Ahh sorry i must have mis read your question

Answer (score 0):

"Theme" options panels that do more than adjust the visual aspects of the site are a nuisance. They shouldn't bundle SEO into them, they shouldn't bundle custom post types. Specifically, they shouldn't ever tie your content to their theme, creating a lock in solution that sucks for long term.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of SEO...there are ample plugins in for that. I find some of the biggest request for features is the placement of meta information with respect to the post. Whether Category or Tags are listed above or belove an entry. Or font size or company information in the footer.  I guess there has to be some 80/20 rule that exist out there regarding must have theme options..