# Options Theme - Wordpress

Tags: theme-options, framework

Searching about options page, I found a lot of themes that uses a options theme page like this one:

[image]

There is an pre-built option? What framework do you advise?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [framework for plugin/theme options panel?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7472/framework-for-plugin-theme-options-panel)

Comment: To answer your first question: no, there is no built-in framework, just the API. Your second question is unfortunately a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the [Option Framework Theme](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/) and [Plugin](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-plugin/). They are killer solutions IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I have had great success with Lee Mason's [NHP Theme Options Framework](http://leemason.github.com/NHP-Theme-Options-Framework/) .

It is super easy to get up and running, but very powerful at the same time. It is setup as a default in my stock base theme that I start projects with now. HTH

Answer (score 1):

The one in your picture is an old version of Options Framework by WP Theming
http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/